# Invoking Linker Cross-Site-Iframe Ignoring the following script tags in the gwt.xml file

Tags: gwt, iframe

```
    //Smart_gwt_exmp.gwt.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


    <module rename-to='smart_gwt_exmp'>

      <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>  
      <inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt"/>

      <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>

      <entry-point class='package2.client.Smart_gwt_exmp'/>

      <source path='client'/>
      <source path='shared'/>

      <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
      <set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/>

    </module>

    //Smart_gwt_exmp.html

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Smart_gwt_exmp.css">


        <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>
       <script src="smart_gwt_exmp/sc/modules/ISC_Calendar.js"></script>
       <script src="smart_gwt_exmp/sc/modules/ISC_Containers.js"></script>
       <script src="smart_gwt_exmp/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js"></script>
       <script src="smart_gwt_exmp/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js"></script>   
       <script src="smart_gwt_exmp/sc/modules/ISC_Drawing.js"></script>  
       <script src="smart_gwt_exmp/sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js"></script>
       <script src="smart_gwt_exmp/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js"></script>
       <script src="smart_gwt_exmp/sc/modules/ISC_History.js"></script>
       <script src="smart_gwt_exmp/sc/modules/ISC_PluginBridges.js"></script>
       <script src="smart_gwt_exmp/sc/modules/ISC_RichTextEditor.js"></script>
       <script src="smart_gwt_exmp/sc/modules/ISC_Scheduler.js"></script>
       <script src="smart_gwt_exmp/sc/modules/ISC_Workflow.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
         src="smart_gwt_exmp/smart_gwt_exmp.nocache.js"></script>

      </head>

      <body>

        <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
        <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1'  
         style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

        <!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript enabled -->
        <noscript>

            Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
            in order for this application to display correctly.
          </div>
        </noscript>

        <h1>Web Application Starter Project</h1>

        <table align="center">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Please enter your name:</td>        
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="nameFieldContainer"></td>
            <td id="sendButtonContainer"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="color:red;" id="errorLabelContainer"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>



 //Smart_gwt_exmp.java

    package package2.client;

    import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
    import com.smartgwt.client.util.SC;
    import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.IButton;
    import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.DynamicForm;
    import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.TextItem;

    /**
     * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
     */
    public class Smart_gwt_exmp implements EntryPoint {

        public void onModuleLoad() {

            DynamicForm form=new DynamicForm();

        }   
    }
```

//Error during compilation
    //Compiling 5 permutations
    //   Compiling permutation 0...
    //  Compiling permutation 1...
    // Compiling permutation 2...
    // Compiling permutation 3...
    // Compiling permutation 4...
    // Compile of permutations succeeded
    // Linking into C:\Users\rsoni\workspace\smart_gwt_exmp\war\smart_gwt_exmp
    //  Invoking Linker Cross-Site-Iframe
    //  Ignoring the following script tags in the gwt.xml file
    //  sc/modules/ISC_Core.js
    //   sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js
    //    sc/modules/ISC_Containers.js
    //   sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js
    //   sc/modules/ISC_Forms.js
    //   sc/modules/ISC_RichTextEditor.js
    //  sc/modules/ISC_Calendar.js
    // sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js
    // sc/skins/Enterprise/load_skin.js

```
//Link succeeded
//Compilation succeeded -- 92.377s
```

//Note : when i try to compile the above code the compiler gives  me the error .The       //error i have pasted in the above code along with the output.

Comment: And so, what's your question exactly?

Comment: i cant able to compile the program .gwt compiler ignores the js files even if i put it in the public folder where should i put the js files that is required in smartgwt

Comment: `Compilation succeeded` doesn't look like a failed build to me. DO you mean that it compiles but doesn't work? Well, your code doesn't do much… Also check your output directory and your browser's dev tools for errors loading resources or executing scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The `std` linker uses `document.write()` to load the script files and make sure they're loaded before the `onModuleLoad` is called.

The `xsiframe` is a much better web citizen and loads everything asynchronously, without `document.write()`. That means it cannot provide those ordering guarantees, so to make the implementaition simpler and, most importantly, reliable, it doesn't support `<script>`s in the gwt.xml files.

By default, it fails the build if you have a `<script>`. You can turn the error into a warning using the `xsiframe.failIfScriptTag` configuration property, but then it ignores the `<script>`s, so you still have to load them by yourself, either right from your HTML host page (like you did BTW, so assuming you listed all needed files, it should work), or using the `ScriptInjector`.

Comment: I put the js file into the html(host file ) than also it is ignoring within the .gwt.xml file

Comment: GWT doesn't look at your HTML, so it'll always print that line. Now the question is: does it work?

Comment: it compiles properly when i run the program in development mode it gives me the exception :[ERROR] [gxtextension] - Failed to load module 'gxtextension' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0' at localhost:51958\                                                     10:54:08.141 [ERROR] [gxtextension] Unable to load module entry point class com.jkv.GxtExtension.client.GxtExtension
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.gwtext.client.widgets.Component::checkExtVer()([]): $wnd.Ext is undefined

Comment: Looks like you need to somehow add a `<script>` for Ext.js (BTW, GWT-Ext is a wrapper around Ext.js, GXT –aka ExtGWT– is a pure GWT lib by Sencha)